# How to stop the script drush if previous command failed?

Tags: drush

Any idea how can I tell the script/drush to stop when the previous command failed?

Ex:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
echo "Disabling parallel config..."
drush vset parallel_enabled 0 

drush vset preprocess_css 0
drush vset preprocess_js 0
drush cc all 

# Disable Mobile theme  
echo "Disabling Mobile theme..."
drush dis --yes mobiletheme

# Disable Zen theme  
echo "Disabling Zen..."
drush dis --yes zen 

# Running the site to offline mode  
echo "Running site in offline mode..."
drush vset --yes site_offline 1 

# Deleting node revisions
echo "Deleting node revisions..."
drush delete-revisions -y

echo "Clearing all the caches..."
drush cc all 

# Rename duplicate files
echo "Renaming duplicate files..."
drush rename-duplicate-files

drush pm-uninstall publication_date -y
drush pm-uninstall date -y
drush pm-uninstall custom_pagers -y 
drush pm-uninstall custom_breadcrumbs -y
```

I want something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
echo "Disabling parallel config..."
drush vset parallel_enabled 0 
if [ ! success ]; then
  echo "The command failed to execute."
  exit
fi
```

Comment: Not sure who voted to close, but I disagree with that.  The question may not be directly related to Drupal, but it is a Drupal activity and I can see this question helping future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the run_cmd function in this file: [base_functions](https://github.com/letharion/Drupal-build-scripts/blob/master/base_functions.sh), which wraps any command and terminates the script if it fails.

You should also be able to do something like:

```
drush cc all || exit;
```

where exit will only run if the previous command fails, and you could replace exit with a call to a function that outputs a more meaningful error message. You may also add a number between 1 and 255 after `exit` to have your script emit an exit status [that can be used further using `$?`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) in any other script calling this one.

Comment: Hi Letharion..the drush always return `0` status no matter what. Like I run the `drush updb -y` outside the Drupal and it complains that I cannot run `drush updb -y`  coz  `Command updatedb needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.` so I assumed that the status is not equal to zero since the command failed. Any idea?

Comment: That is not the case for me. `drush updb; echo $?` yields 1 when invalid, while `drush help; echo $?` always yields 0. This also triggers the expected response when using either `&&` or `||` for me. Using drush 4.5 and bash 4.2.